# ModX: Resource alias not automatically inserting slash in URL

Tags: url, alias, modx, modx-revolution

A weird one: I have a site using ModX and this morning when I went to preview a page after editing a got and error. It seems that ModX is no longer placing the `/` before the Resource Alias.

Thus my URL becomes `mysite.comabout-us` instead of `mysite.com/about-us` and doesnt work

Putting in the slash manually has no effect as ModX removes it on save.

Im running Revo 2.1.3

Would anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

EDIT: 
Did some more testing and discovered this also occurs when I turn FURLs off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so took a stab in the dark and looked through the config.inc.php file and changed:

`$modx_base_url= '';` to `$modx_base_url= '/';` and all seems to be well again... Really odd